# How do I only use one column of imported text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files, multiple-columns

In my code I am importing 3 different list of names and numbers and I want to get the names that occur least often.  Right now I get a list of all the names and how many times they occur.  But the code also counts  all the other columns that I do not need.

1. How do I only analyze the data of 1 column of the text files?

2.Only get out and answer with words that occur once, not multiple times?

```
import re

filelist = ['D.txt','A.txt','S.txt']
wordbank = {}
for file in filelist:
    article_one = re.findall('\w+', open(file,).read().lower())

    for word in article_one:
        word = word.lower().strip(string.punctuation)
        if word not in wordbank:
            wordbank[word] = 1
        else:
            wordbank[word] += 1

sortedwords = sorted(wordbank.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))

for word in sortedwords:
    print (word[1], word[0])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What separates your columns in the text files? For the sake of example, lets say they are tab separated columns. Rather than use regular expressions, all you need to do is read in each line of the text file and split the line by `'\t'`. Then to use only the first column, take index zero of the list that contains your split line.

What you are doing with wordbank should suffice for finding words that occur only once. All you have to do is take check the count of each word to make sure it is not greater than 1. For example:

```
filelist = ['D.txt','A.txt','S.txt']
wordbank = {}
for file in filelist:
    f = open(file, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    for l in lines:
        line = l.split('\t')
        word = line[0]

        if word not in wordbank:
            wordbank[word] = 1
        else:
            wordbank[word] += 1
    f.close()

# Gather unique words
unique_words = []
for word in wordbank.keys():
    if wordbank[word] == 1:
        unique_words.append(word)
```

Comment: I'm not getting any response from the unique_words code

Comment: I provided code above that shows how to gather the unique words. When the for loop completes, you will have a list of only the unique_words.